# How to show marker on google map when clicked on list item from hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on google maps. I want to link markers to items in menu. If I click the the name, it should show respective marker only. But my code is pointing to only last marker in the map.

All my links are pointing to last marker. Please help me solving this problem.

```
<div class="menu">
     <div data-bind="foreach: visible">
        <p class="clicked" data-bind="text: location, click"></p>
     </div>
</div>
```

javaScript:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
    var loc = markersData[i].locationId;
    var name = markersData[i].location;

    $('.clicked').on('click', function() {

        if ($('.clicked').location = name) {
            console.log(location);
            createMarker(latlng, loc);

        }
    });
```

I changed the code but this one is displaying all the markers at a time on clicking single link.

```
function displayMarkers() {

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

     for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat,markersData[i].lng);
         var loc = markersData[i].locationId;
         var name = markersData[i].location;

         checkLinkClicked(latlng, loc, name);
         createMarker(latlng, loc);

         bounds.extend(latlng);
     }

     map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }

 function checkLinkClicked(latlng, loc, name) {

     $(’.clicked’).on(‘click’, function() {

         if ((’.clicked’).location = name) {
             createMarker(latlng, loc);

         }
     });
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi Aaqib... Thanks for formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439915/google-map-click-marker-by-external-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351008/open-infowindows-from-an-external-link-outside-of-the-google-map

Comment: Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajeshchv/4ndac40u/7/) doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the question. I went through the related questions but I am unable to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this working sample. http://jsbin.com/tayope/edit?html,js,output

This is just a basic demo that demonstrates the functionality you need. Ignore the layout/design.

Here's a sample item in the menu with an onClick event:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="showMarker(1)">Marker 1</a></li>
```

When the user clicks an item in the menu, it will basically show the specific marker in the map.

```
function showMarker(index) {
  hideAllMarkers();
  markers[index - 1].setMap(map);
}
```

You can either pass the index or add it as a data attribute of the menu item.

Here is the code snippet as well: (try to open it in full screen)

```js
var map;
var coordinates = [
  {
    lat: 14.534472,
    lng: 121.052367 
  },
  {
    lat: 14.532709,
    lng: 121.05333 
  },
  {
    lat: 14.533593,
    lng: 121.053128 
  }
]
var markers = []

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 14.533593, lng: 121.053128},
    zoom: 15,
  });
  
  for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates[i],
        map: map
      });
      marker.setMap(null);
      markers.push(marker);
  }
}

function showMarker(index) {
  hideAllMarkers();
  markers[index - 1].setMap(map);
}

function hideAllMarkers() {
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
    height: 500px !important;
  margin: auto;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Markers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="showMarker(1)">Marker 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="showMarker(2)">Marker 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="showMarker(3)">Marker 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```